# I have animal crossing new leaf amiibo and i wanna transfer my data to the plain animal crossing new leaf game

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I bought animal crossing new leaf amiibo a while ago and i got the plain animal crossing new leaf game for my birthday by mistake. I wanna transfer my game data to the plain game because i couldn't join my friend's towns before because they had the plain version. How do i transfer the data and can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

*Animal Crossing: New Leaf* and *Animal Crossing: New Leaf - Welcome Amiibo* are basically the same game. Installing updates will transform *New Leaf* into the *Welcome Amiibo* edition. It doesn’t matter which edition of the game a player owns for multiplayer, so long as they have installed the latest updates.

If you have the cartridge version of each edition of the game, your save file cannot be moved or copied from one cartridge to another.